# Fixed point theorem involving nonexpansive mapping on uniformly convex Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

This is an exercise from the Dirk Werner's book about fixed point theorem: Let $X$ be a uniformly convex Banach space. Let $F:B_X\to X$ be a nonexpansive mapping, i.e.
$$ \forall x,y\in B_X: \|F(x)-F(y)\|\leq \|x-y\|.$$
Here denotes $B_X$ the closed unit ball in $X$. Then

1. Either $F$ has a fixed point, or there exists some $x\in S_X$ and some $\lambda>1$ such that $F(x)=\lambda x$. Here $S_X$ denotes the unit sphere of $X$.
2. If $F(S_X)\subset B_X$, then $F$ has a fixed point.

I am still working with 1. What I tried is to assume that $F$ has no fixed point. In this case, the range of $F$ is contained in the ball $B_{1+\|F(0)\|}$, and using rescaling one easily concludes that $F(x)=\lambda x$ for some $x\in B_X$ and $\lambda>1$. However, I am not able to conclude that the point $x$ is exactly a point on the sphere.

Any advice and suggestion is very welcome!

---

Some thoughts: To show the statement (assuming no fixed points) it is equivalent to show that the function $(F(z)-z)/\|F(z)-z\|$ has a fixed point. Notice that this function has image in $S_X$, so one might want to apply the Browder's FPT to this function stated in the Werner's textbook. However, it is no more nonexpansive now, so my goal is to construct a new function, derived from this one, which has image in $B_X$ and nonexpansive.

Comment: (1/2) I assume that you currently show existence of $\lambda$ and $x$ by applying Banach's fixed point theorem to $\lambda^{-1}F$ for large enough $\lambda$. A couple of observations: $(1)$ this argument doesn't use that $F$ has no fixed point anywhere. $(2)$ it is not the case that the $x$ you find must lie on the unit sphere unless you pick $\lambda$ more cleverly. For example, $\lambda = (1+ \|F(0)\|)$ appears to be the natural choice. However, if $X = \ell^2$ and $F(x) = (1, x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$ then $F$ is even isometric and for $\lambda > 1$, $F(x) = \lambda x$ if and only if...

Comment: (2/2) $x_n = \lambda^{-n}$. Then we have $\|x\|_2 = (\lambda^2 - 1)^{-\frac12}$ so $\|x\|_2 = 1$ if and only if $\lambda = \sqrt{2}$. However, $(1+ \|F(0)\|_2) = 2$. This means it is clear that you must pick a particular $\lambda$.

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, this is exactly my problem. Actually I have a new idea, to show the statement (assuming no fixed points) it is equivalent to show that the function $(F(z)-z)/\|F(z)-z\|$ has a fixed point. Notice that this function has image in $S_X$, so one might want to apply the Browder's FPT to this function stated in the Werner's textbook. However, it is no more nonexpansive now, so my goal is to construct a new function, derived from this one, which has image in $B_X$ and nonexpansive.

Comment: Maybe the idea I spent a little bit of time pursuing but couldn't quite get to work out will work better for you. I considered $\lambda_0 = \inf\{ \lambda > 1: \text{ there is an } x \text{ such that } F(x) = \lambda x\}$. Since $X$ is uniformly convex (and hence reflexive) you can check that this $\inf$ is a minimum (and strictly greater than $1$) and then consider $x_0$ such that $F(x_0) = \lambda_0 x_0$. My guess is that $\|x_0\| = 1$  by some argument using the minimality of $\lambda_0$ but I couldn't quite get anything to work out.

Comment: @RhysSteele No problem, thank you very much for your effort, I will give a try.

Comment: @RhysSteele sorry, but can you spell out the argument why the $\inf$ is a min? Are you saying the inf will be a min for any reflexive space?

Comment: @mathworker21 It's good that you asked! I realised whilst trying to write out details here, I carelessly implicitly used a result regarding strong vs weak continuity that is untrue for non-linear operators. Sorry about that!

Comment: @RhysSteele Also, the argument the OP used required that $0$ is not a fixed point. I wonder whether it is true that [$0$ not a fixed point] implies [there is some eigenvector on the sphere with eigenvalue greater than $1$]

Comment: @mathworker21 The argument I described in the comments doesn't though. OP only uses it to see that the $\lambda$ they take isn't equal to $1$ (which wouldn't be a problem) You could remove the assumption that $F(0) \neq 0$ and do the whole argument again to see that there is some $\lambda \geq 1$ and $x \in B_X$ with $F(x) = \lambda x$. For the second part of your comment, just consider $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $F(x) = -x + 1$.

Comment: @RhysSteele thanks! wait, did you mean "there is some $\lambda > 1$ and $x \in B_X$ with $F(x) = \lambda x$"? We need $\lambda > 1$.

Comment: @mathworker21 We don't need $\lambda > 1$. We need $\lambda \geq 1$. If $\lambda = 1$ then we get a fixed point which is one of the two outcomes we wanted.

Comment: @mathworker21 Brouwer's fixed point theorem only works in finite dimensional spaces I'm afraid. The usual results in this setting are Browder's fixed point theorem (the name is not a typo of Brouwer's FPT) which requires uniform convexity and non-expansitivity (so looks applicable here) or Schauder's FPT which requires some kind of compactness. The problem with the function you mention for Browder's FPT is that it is not non-expansive.

Comment: @RhysSteele yes, thanks a lot for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here I want to give an incomplete answer which is only valid for the case that $X$ is a Hilbert space. Suppose there is no FP and we want to show the second statement. We first claim that for each $x_0\in X$, there is a unique point $x\in B_X$ such that
$$ |x_0-x|=\inf_{y\in B_X}|x_0-y|.$$
Indeed, let $(x_n)$ be a minimizing sequence in $B_X$. since it is a minimizing sequence, it must be bounded and therefore it has a weakly convergence subsequence due to the reflexivity of $X$, which converges to some $x\in B_X$. Using the weakly lower semicontinuity of the norm function we immediately infer that $x$ is our sought. Suppose there are two such minimizers $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $x_1\neq x_2$, then $\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)\in B_X$, since $B_X$ is convex, and
\begin{align}
&|x_0-\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)|\\
<& \frac{1}{2}(|x_0-x_1|+|x_0-x_2|)\\
=&\frac{1}{2}(d+d)=d,
\end{align}
where $d$ is the distance of $x_0$ to $B_X$ and the strict inequality is due to the strict convexity of $X$. But this constradicts the minimality of $d$. Thus $x$ is uniquely determined. thus the function $P$ given by $P(x_0)=x$ for $x_0\in X$ is well-defined. In fact, $P$ is the projection onto $B_X$ and it is well known that $P$ is nonexpansive (for a proof, see for instance Prop.2 in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01109805)). Clearly, if $|x|\leq 1$, then $P(x)=x$. The most important observation is that 
$$ P(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$$
for $|x|>1$. Suppose it was not the case, then using the minimal distance property of $P(x)$ one could find some $y\in B_X$ such that
$$ |x-\frac{x}{|x|}|>|y-x|\geq |x|-|y|$$
and it follows 
$$ |y|>\frac{|x|}{|x|}=1,$$
contradiction. Now we consider the function 
$$ G(x)=(P\circ F)(x).$$
From the previous mentioned claims it follows that $G$ is from $B_X$ to $B_X$ and nonexpansive. Thus using the Browder's FPT we can find a FP $x\in B_X$ of $G$, i.e.,
$$ x=G(x)=(P\circ F)(x).$$ 
If $|F(x)|\leq 1$, then it follows $(P\circ F)(x)=F(x)$, thus $x$ is a FP of $F$, which is impossible due to the given assumption. Thus $|F(x)|>1$, and therefore
$$ x=(P\circ F)(x)=\frac{F(x)}{|F(x)|}.$$
In this case we obtain that $|x|=1$ and the claim is fulfilled for this $x\in S_X$ with $\lambda=|F(x)|>1$.

In general, this method can not be adopted to the case where $X$ is a Banach space. The failure is due to the fact that the projection $P$ is not necessarily nonexpansive. Nevertheless, it seems possible to define the so called generalized metric projection (see [this paper](https://www.functionaldifferentialequations.com/index.php/fde/article/download/590/565)) to modify this method for Banach spaces. But this is in no meaning trivial for an exercise given in a textbook (particularly, nothing involving this topic is given in the book), so I will maybe skip this part.